# Xcode 7 missing setter or instance variable

Tags: xcode, swift, instance, setter

I just have a strange trouble. I written a test app, that searches min & max of array values. In first times apps works normally, but only had a warning: "Array MinMax[554:5057] Failed to connect (exitNow) outlet from (Array_MinMax.ViewController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable"

Now, several days later, i started app again, enter some values, pushed button and app instantly crush with same error:

```
2016-06-15 12:11:40.910 Array MinMax[829:18846] Failed to connect (exitNow) outlet from (Array_MinMax.ViewController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable
```

(lldb)

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var inputArrayValues: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var minLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBAction func exitNow(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }
    @IBAction func arrayMinMax(sender: AnyObject) {

        let someData: String? = inputArrayValues.stringValue
        let separators = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ,;:|")
        let parts = someData!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separators)

        let intArray = parts.map{Double($0)}

        let minArray = intArray.minElement({$0 < $1}) // - stops on that line (thread 1: breakpoint 1.1)
        let maxArray = intArray.maxElement({$0 < $1})

        let minString = String(minArray!)
        let maxString = String(maxArray!)

        minLabel.stringValue = "The minimal value is \(minString)!"
        maxLabel.stringValue = "The maximal value is \(maxString)!"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

What to do with that, i can't understand! Is it a bug of Xcode 7.3.1??

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this trouble. Just recreated the button using "NSButton" instead of "Any Object". Then, error goes away!